# 'unrecognized selector' crash on indexPath.section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a grouped UITableView (2 rows, with the first row with the data), and am trying to populate it with data from Facebook, but for some reason I am having a difficult time with it. 
When I try and populate it with an NSDictionary, it crashes with 'unrecognized selector', even though (to my knowledge) I have everything setup properly.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *album; 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *fbArray; 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *album_amount;



-(void)viewDidLoad 
{ 
  [super viewDidLoad]; 
  self.tableView.delegate = self; 
  self.tableview.dataSource = self; 

  [self requestAlbums]; // Here, I request the user's albums from FB
}

- (void)requestAlbums 
{
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/albums/"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
{
                          TBAppDelegate *delegate = (TBAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

                          managedObjectContext = [delegate managedObjectContext];

                          if(error)
                          {
                              return;
                          }

                          NSArray* collection = (NSArray*)[result data];

                          self.album = [collection objectAtIndex:0];

                          self.album_amount = collection;

    for (int i=0; i  < self.album_amount.count; i++)
    {
        self.album = [self.album_amount objectAtIndex:i];
        self.photoFQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/photos", [self.album objectForKey:@"id"]];

        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:self.photoFQL completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
         {
         }];

        self.fbArray = [self.album objectForKey:@"name"];

                }


                      }];       
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d", indexPath.row + 1];

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell.tag == 0)
{        
    NSDictionary *albumDict = [self.fbArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]; // Here's where the error is thrown, and I don't know why. I've gone through tutorials, and they either tell me to use indexPath.section or indexPath.row (I have to use indexPath.section as I am using a grouped tableview, right)? 

    NSLog(@"%@", [albumDict objectForKey:@"name"]);

}

if (cell.tag == 1)
{
}

return cell;
}
```

Comment: whats the error message? unrecognized selector send to what?

Comment: It's [__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc35a590

Comment: so `NSArray* collection = (NSArray*)[result data];` is not NSArray, it is NSString

Comment: So what you are saying is I should switch NSArray to NSString?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the result object is in since its just an ID.

log it out though.

```
NSLog (@"result class: %@", NSStringFromClass([result class]));
```

If its a string or NSData, you'll need to JSON parse it.
If its an NSDictionary, you'll need to access the data using keys.

Comment: The result object is FBGraphObject, part of the Facebook SDK. I guess I'll need to parse it

Comment: Actually FBGraphObject integrates like an NSDictionary, you should just NSLog the result then pick out what you want from it.